# How does for(var x in object) work if there is initially no var x in the object, initially?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object, and I'm trying to see what's inside of it.  So, I used `print(object)`, which should possibly contain `Spot: True`, indicating that the cat Spot is alive.  It returned `[object object]`.  So, I tried, `show(object)`, and I got `Spot: True`.  I think that's right, but I'm not sure what the indexes are like.  For example, I'm not sure if the keys are associative or numeric, or even if associative arrays are allowed in JavaScipt.

The reason I wonder why is because `for (var cats in object){show(cats);}` returns `Spot`.  I can't find a way to locate the string 'cat' as being part of the array.

Comment: `cats` is a variable, just like `x` is in: `var x = 42;`. Btw, `show` is not a built-in JavaScript function.

Comment: Felix, that's why I wish they had included the code that makes show work....  I know that cats is a variable.  That's obvious.  What's not obvious is why a program would enumerate everything 'cats' in an object when there is nothing 'cats' in the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cats` in your example is a *new* variable that holds each object of iteration.

And yes, "associative arrays" are allowed, but they're really just objects:

```
var foo = {
    bar: "baz"
}
alert(foo.bar);
alert(foo["bar"]);
```

Re: the `for/in` statement: it's more or less the same as the following, here using an array:

```
var cats;
var arr = [42, 69];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    cats = arr[i];
    alert(cats);
}
```

Or you can use `for/in` and it becomes:

```
for (cats in arr) {
    alert(arr[cats]);
}
```

It's slightly different for arrays, but there's no "cats" in the array, either.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/4ePmW/)

Comment: Dave, it sounds like you're the closest to an answer that I can understand.  Could you please see the reply thread to the question?

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Variable names are arbitrary; perhaps "Spot" is the name of the writer's cat? I can't speak to *why* that name was chosen, but it doesn't have anything to do with the contents of the array from a *technical* standpoint. From a *cognitive* standpoint, it should, to make it easy to read and understand the code.

Comment: Dave, I understand why Spot is in the object.  There is a line of code: `var livingCats = {Spot: "True"};`.  I don't understand why `var cats` enumerates the array because it doesn't exist as a key or value in the object.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 ... That's just how JavaScript works. When you say `for (anyVariable in anObject)`, the value of `anyVariable` is set to each property of that object, as the object's properties are iterated over. The variable `cats` doesn't "enumerate the array", the `for` statement enumerates the array, and sets the value of `cats` to each array entry during enumeration. I'll edit the answer to see if I can make it any clearer, but there isn't much else that can be said.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 (And if an answer answers your question, it should be accepted.)

Comment: Dave, I don't think any of the answers do.  Only the comments following your answer.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Well, IMO they all kind of answer it, because they all show that the *name* of the variable isn't relevant, but sometimes it just takes saying it in multiple ways before it sinks in :)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has arrays and objects. Arrays have numeric continuous indexes `[0..length)` and ordered while objects can have random indexes (strings, numbers) and are not necessarily ordered (depends on the implementation).

Using `for(var key in obj) {}` should only be used for objects and iterates over the properties the object has. You can use `obj[var]` to access the *value* of each property.
Note that it's useful to add an `if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;` check to the loop to ensure you do not hit properties introduced in the object's prototype.

Comment: I think in my case, show(object); is giving me the return format `{index: value}`.  I wish the writer of the book had shown us how the source works for show.  I guess just typing 'object' flat-out, you get the index-value pair in a console.

Answer (score 0):

If `object` is your object, I'm guessing it's not actually an array. The `for (var x in object)` could also be enumerating the elements (properties, functions, etc.) of your object.

Where does your `object` come from? What are `show()` and `print()`?

If I was trying to print out the properties of an object I might have something like this:

```
var myObject = {
    property1: 'Test',
    property2: 'Test2',
    function1: function() {
        // do something
    }
};

for (var prop in myObject) {
    if (myObject.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        console.log(prop + ' = ' + myObject[prop]);
    }
}
```

This should output the following:

```
property1 = Test
property2 = Test2
function1 = function() { // do something }
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhCfh/) to show the example.

With that said, JavaScript doesn't really have associative arrays. What you can have is an object with property:value pairs, which is what I think you have.